# Zoo Visitor:details Ajax request

Tags: forms, login, zoo-visitor, ajax

I am using malsups form.js to run a login script combined with the zoo visitor add-on. When the login form has been successful the user is successfully logged in with out any need of a page refresh, although when I want to display the username the page needs to be refreshed for those details to appear on screen. Below is my code, any suggestions ?

--

```
                        <div class="username_wrap">
                            <p>Welcome 
                                <span>
                                    {exp:zoo_visitor:details}
                                            {visitor:member_firstname}
                                    {/exp:zoo_visitor:details}
                                </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
```

$("#userLoginForm").ajaxForm({

dataType: "json",
                success: function (event) {

```
                if (event.success) {
                    member_favourites = "5";
                    //do something
                } 
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a hidden template that is just the logged in username only. Then load it in via jquery ajax .load(); Once login is complete as well.

```
               if (event.success) {
                    member_favourites = "5";
                    //do something
                    $("div#username").load("_username.html");
                }
```

Comment: Champion! appreciate that

Comment: Glad to help holler if you need anything else @buildmidwestern

Answer (score 0):

With this code it's working fine:

```
            $('#form').ajaxForm({
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        $("#jqxwindow ").jqxWindow({ height:150,
                                                    width: 250,
                                                    theme: 'bootstrap',
                                                    content: 'Você é registrado',
                                                    resizable: false
                                                                        });
                        $('#jqxwindow').on('close', function (event) {
                            alert("You closed a window");
                           );


                    } else {
                        alert('Failed with the following errors: '+data.errors.login);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Your code is in the header or footer?? If footer, you have to wrap it with document ready:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

the code here

});
```

In the example code, the box message are from the Jqx framework , but with a simple js alert box it will work too.

Comment: Hi Stephane, yes that example does work in regards to showing if an ajaxForm is working, although i need to know how to change the zoo visitor details after a user logs in asynchronously. Hope that makes sense. User still needs to refresh the page to see the visitor:details